# tinyMCE get editor returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I initialize 2 tinyMCE editor on 2 textarea with different id :

```
var variable_array = {id:'cName', test:'mon test'};
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#model_editor",
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    theme: "modern",
    height: "500px",
    width: "100%",
    variables_list : variable_array,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern modelinsert"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    toolbar2: "variable_insert | question_insert",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: "#headerfooter_editor",
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    theme: "modern",
    height: "500px",
    width: "100%",
    variables_list : variable_array,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern modelinsert"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    toolbar2: "variable_insert | question_insert",
    image_advtab: true,
    init_instance_callback : "mceInitInstance",
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
```

Both editors init correctly.
Then in order to set different content on each, I try to get the editor instance object id :

```
var editor_id = tinyMCE.get('#headerfooter_editor');
console.log(editor_id);
```

It returns null :/

I try also to get in the console the result of the callback of the second init :

```
function mceInitInstance(inst) {

console.log("Editor: " + inst.editorId + " is now initialized.");
```

And it returns : Editor: undefined is now initialized.

I want to do the following :

```
tinyMCE.get('#headerfooter_editor').setContent(data.content);
```

but of course it returns an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of null

I don't understand what's wrong and why I can't get the editor instance id :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your editors should be available using `tinymce.get('model_editor')` and `tinymce.get('headerfooter_editor')`.

**Hint**: `tinymce.editors` holds all editor instances that have been initialized.
You can loop through that array to get them all:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++)
{
    console.log("Editor id:", tinymce.editors[i].id);
}
```

Comment: As you can see both textarea have a different id : #model_editor and #headerfooter_editor
Moreover I use get with the id, sorry but I don't understand your answer.

Comment: answer edited. type this in your console and tell me what you get: tinymce.editors

Comment: you should be able to use tinyMCE.get('headerfooter_editor') then

Comment: ok so by removing the # in the get parameter I finally got a result : "k {documentBaseUrl: "http://xxxxx.xxx/xxx/", settings: Object, id: "headerfooter_editor", isNotDirty: true, plugins: Object…}"

Comment: but then I try to set the content of the editor returned by the get (as on the official documentation):
       tinyMCE.get('headerfooter_editor').setContent(data.content);

I have checked before that data.content is a valid string and is not null, but it doesn't set anything in the editor :/

Comment: i've done a getContent and the content is in.... but not displayed in the editor.... and I've just noticed that I cannot even type in the editor....

Comment: do you still got the problems described?

Comment: yes, I have tried to keep only one editor but still got the issue :/

Comment: gonna open a new question in the afternoon... feel free to participate^^

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

`tinyMCE.get('#headerfooter_editor').setContent(data.content);`

use

`tinyMCE.get('headerfooter_editor').setContent(data.content);`

remove `#`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.
The error message was:

```
TypeError: tinymce.get(...) is null
```

But my error was that I tried to `tinymce.get(...)` before initiating tinymce editor.

```
tinymce.init({selector: "#mytextarea"})
```